# TFS 2012 Express add user with limitations

Tags: tfs

I have installed TFS 2012 Express where I have a workspace with multiple solutions inside.
 What I want to do is to create users to TFS for different solutions. 
Lets say my solutions are

1-Provider
2-Mixer
3-Web
4-Control

I want to create a user who is only allowed to work on "Mixer" solution , and make changes to it. But dont want him to see other solutions("Provider" , " Web" , "Control") .

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

In Source Control Explorer, right click, Advanced, Security.
**Deny**  the **Read** permission to the folder that contains the solution for all the users except those you want to see it.

You can also get to the security options via the Web Access under "Code" and right clicking.